# Composite Keys in EF 4.2 Code First

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I have the following Classes and am using EF 4.2 Code First

```
public class PartAttribute
{
    public Part Part { get; set; }

    public PartAttributeType PartAttributeType { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] Time { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Part
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public PartType PartType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Team> SelectedTeams { get; set; }
}

public class PartAttributeType
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public PartType PartType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

When I build my model it creates the three tables and the relationships between the tables as I would like/expect them.  I am trying to create a composite key on the PartAttribute table between the Part, PartAttributeType, and the time and I can't seem to figure it out.  When I try to add 
`modelBuilder.Entity<PartAttribute>().HasKey(c => new { c.Part, c.PartAttributeType, c.Time });`
I get an error saying Part is not a scalar type (which it is not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to introduce foreign key properties which can act as primary keys at the same time:

```cs
public class PartAttribute
{
    public Guid PartId { get; set; }
    public Guid PartAttributeTypeId { get; set; }

    public Part Part { get; set; }

    public PartAttributeType PartAttributeType { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] Time { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then your mapping:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<PartAttribute>()
    .HasKey(c => new { c.PartId, c.PartAttributeTypeId, c.Time });
```

EF should be able to recognize the new properties as the foreign keys for your two navigation properties due to the naming convention.

Comment: When I do that I get the following errors.  "The database creation succeeded, but the creation of the database objects did not. See InnerException for details." & "Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'PartAttributeType_PartType' on table 'PartAttributeTypes' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not create constraint. See previous errors."  Any Ideas?

Comment: @PlTaylor: Probably because both `Part` and `PartAttributeType` refer to an entity `PartType` (one-to-many?) which is a required navigation property. You will have to specify `WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` in Fluent mapping for these relationships, something like: `modelBuilder.Entity<Part>().HasRequired(p => p.PartType).WithMany(...).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);` and the same for `PartAttributeType`. It's another problem, not related to the complex key problem.

Comment: You are correct on all accounts about the cascading deletes.  Thanks for your help.